# Overriding the existing CRUD module in Play 1.2.4

Tags: java, web-applications, playframework, crud, playframework-1.x

I am trying to implement CRUD module for managing the user roles in our application.

I followed this link to implement and the basic functionality and template looks good. Now I need to customize it based on my requirement.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/crud

The delete button click is deleting the record from the database but I don't want a permanent delete. We have a delId and delTS in the database. On click of the delete button, I have to update these DB values (i.e. logical delete rather than physical delete).

My initial thought was to override the delete method present in the CRUD in my controller but I am not able to do so. I can see that all the methods present in the CRUD are made as static methods and the controller is extending the CRUD. I wont be able to override the delete method present inside the CRUD.java since it is an static method.

Kindly let me know how to override a the delete button click functionality based on my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the routes files :

```
 DELETE     /admin/roles/{id}   Roles.delete // assuming Roles extends CRUD
```

and define your own delete method in the Roles Controller.